# Removing unnecessary exports from generated .JS files when using webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx

I am writing a .NET Core Web app which uses ReactJs for the front end. Currently I am using webpack with babel to generate my JS files from my JSX source. I have got it working but I have noticed a significant issue with my current set up which I have not been able to resolve.

My current webpack config file looks like this:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

var PROD = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development";

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        firstBundle: "./src/Folder1/AFile.js",
        secondBundle: "./src/Folder1/AnotherFile.js",
        thirdCaseBundle: "./src/Folder2/ThisFile.js",
        fourthBundle: "./src/Folder3/ThatFile.js"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "./wwwroot/js/[name].js"
    },
    plugins: PROD ? [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ] : [],
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            "src",
            "node_modules",
            "src/Folder1",
            "src/Folder2",
            "src/Folder3"
        ]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: { presets: ["env", "react", "stage-0", "stage-2"] }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

This generates my JS files but seems to include every exported function from every module in each of them, not just the modules included in the JavaScript from which the bundle is generated.

For example in the above I'd end up with unrelated exports from Folder2 and Folder3 in my firstBundle.js even though there is nothing in AFile.js that links to them.

Currently this is working but as I add more Modules and more JS files it is becoming unsustainable as each output file grows. I imagine that one solution would be to have a separate webpack config file for each bundle and only reference the modules it needs but I currently have more than 20 bundles and do not want to end up with that number of config files (which would also require me to add 20+ steps to my build in VSTS).